# Выбор места для отправка запроса к серверу

Tags: javascript, vue.js, localstorage, vuex

Подскажите пожалуйста, из какого места лучше отправлять запрос серверу,и записать ответ в `vuex storage`?

**1-ый вариант:** Отправлять запрос из компонента vue, полученные данные передать через `action` в `vuex storage` и мутацией сохранить.

**2-ой вариант:** прописать запрос в `action` `vuex`, и дергать каждый раз этот `action`. В `action` получаем ответ на запрос, сохраняем через мутацию.

Возможно у Вас есть какие-либо ещё варианты, с радостью хочу их узнать!

Comment: Второй вариант однозначно, и всю работу с апи лучше поместить в отдельный модуль Vuex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это единоразовый запрос (уникальный), либо же, если запросы осуществляются только лишь из одного компонета, то подойдет и 1-й вариант.  Если запрос не уникален и может быть выполнен из любого места приложения - то лучше 2-й вариант.

Только, нюанс: если Вы используете 1-й вариант, то результат ответа нужно сохранять сразу, с помощью мутаций, а не через actions